# unknown component after xaml composition

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am trying without success to compose a xaml page with an usercontrol. The purpose is to lighten the main page.
here is the UserControl beginning:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.richTextSummary"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit"
             xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"
             >



    <dxb:BarManager x:Name="barManager1" ToolbarGlyphSize="Small">
```

and here is a part of the mainPage xaml reusing this userControl:

```
<TabControl Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=gridFields}">
                        <TabItem Header="Résumé">
                            <controls:richTextSummary></controls:richTextSummary>

                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem Header="Fin"/>

                    </TabControl>
```

The problem is that in my userControl, I define a component which is given a name (rater) and I initialize this component in the mainpage code behind (in its constructor):

`rater.Value=2;`

It seems that when the constructor is called, the code is not injected and parsed... 
Have you got a idea to solve this?

Comment: When do you exect the rater value to be set? Is the Résumé tab selected? Are you seeing the richTextSummary UserControl?

Comment: the rater value is set in mainWindow's constructor, and the third question was good : at design time, in visual studio, I get an alert saying the "type 'controls:richTextSummary' can't be found."

Comment: MainWindow? What is rater and where is it defined? And I was referring to the runtime behaviour rather than the design time experience.

Comment: tthere's not really a

Comment: tthere's not really a runtime behavior : there are errors that prevent running. rater is a rating component(with stars), and the behavior in visual studio is very awkward : the component is displayed in VS's conceptor view, but below in the xaml code there is the error  I just reported... the rater is definer in the UserControl, deep in the nested xml tags of the userControl. In the usercontrol conceptor view, the rater is displayed correctly (at design time obviously)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just a copy&paste error but I noticed that you are missing the namespace-declaration for the DevExpress-Bars assembly! Could that be the cause of your problem?

```
xmlns:dxb="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/bars"
```

Comment: thank you, but it's not that, even with this line added the problem remains the same